# Passing image to email in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, html-email

I am attempting to send an email with a image embedded in the html code. I have verified that the image is being accessed but, I'm not able to see the image when I get the email.

Trigger In Views:

```
try:
    logo = base64.b64encode(open("dashboard/static/assets/abc.png", "rb").read()).decode()

    current_site = get_current_site(request)
    mail_subject = 'Welcome to AV Support'
    message = render_to_string('activation_email.html', {
        'user': user,
        'domain': current_site.domain,
        'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
        'token': default_token_generator.make_token(user),
        'logo':logo
    })


    plain_message = strip_html(message)

    email = send_mail(
        mail_subject, message=plain_message,html_message=message, recipient_list=[
            user.email], from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    )
    email 
    print('EMAIL SENT')
except Exception as e:
    print('NO EMAIL SENT')

    print(e)
```

Passing Logo To Email:

```
      <img src="data:dashboard/static/assets/abc.png;base64,{{logo}}" width="250" height="50" />
```

I have verified that the "logo" has data and the file is in the directory, the email comes up with a blank space. Could someone tell me what needs to be done?